# output bigger than 16384 bytes is lost when using sqlite3_prepare_v2

Tags: c, sqlite

```
      sprintf (Z_Cmd, "SELECT intra_days FROM vwFiveMinutesProduction WHERE ((timestamp > %ld) AND (timestamp <= %ld)) order by timestamp desc;",Z_MiddleDate,Z_EndDate);
      Z_DbResult2 = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (Z_DB,Z_Cmd,-1, &Z_Stmt_Data3,0);
      if (Z_DbResult2 != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to request intraday data second  half : %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(Z_DB));
        exit(20);
      }else {
        Z_DbResult2 = sqlite3_step (Z_Stmt_Data3);
        while (Z_DbResult2 == SQLITE_ROW){
          fprintf (Z_OutputFile,"%s\n"
                          ,(const char *)sqlite3_column_text (Z_Stmt_Data3, 0)); 
          if (Z_ExportFull != true){
            fprintf (Z_OutputFile2,"%s\n"
                          ,(const char *)sqlite3_column_text (Z_Stmt_Data3, 0)); 
          }
          Z_DbResult2 = sqlite3_step (Z_Stmt_Data3);
        }
      }
```

Z_Stmt_Data3 seems to be limited to 16384 bytes (0x4000).
Is this something that can be configured (setting?)?
Can somebody provide an example on how to do this?

Comment: `Z_Stmt_Data3` is presumably a `sqlite3_stmt` struct? Where are you getting this number from and how is it relevant?

Comment: It is a indeed an sqlite3_stmt struct. I exported the output to a file. The dump of data to this file stops always at 4k. That's why I assumed that there might exist a configuration parameter.